# Dask on Hadoop Kubernetes

Tags: hadoop, kubernetes, cluster-computing, dask, kubernetes-helm

I've installed `Hadoop` via a `helm chart` on my `microk8s kubernetes` cluster. 
I would like to know how to create a dask cluster on my different machines on this hadoop cluster. I tried following the the tutorials on the Dask websites, but I keep getting errors because it is looking for the local yarn/hadoop. How do I point to the hadoop on kubernetes so I can create the cluster?

Comment: please add links to the tutorials you've tried as well as error you've got. Have you been checking the https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html ?

Comment: If you have k8s what not launch on k8s instead of hadoop ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch Dask on Yarn we recommend using https://yarn.dask.org

However, if you are using Kubernetes already you might consider https://kubernetes.dask.org, which is more commonly used today.